# How to display images from an ImageField in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Before I explain, I have a question. I am making a blog and the posts have a heading image. I upload this image using admin when I create a post for my blog. Is this image 'static' or 'media'?

Anyway, I have my project set up as follows: 
mysite is my project, blog is my app. I have a folder named static inside blog. Inside this static folder are four more folders- css, images, fonts, js.

In settings.py, I have this set up:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

My models.py looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    header_image = models.ImageField('article_header_image', upload_to = 'blog/static/images/articleimages')
```

Now when I try to load this image in a template, it doesn't show up.

I am doing this the following way:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<img src="{{post.header_image.url}}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Another thing, how can I use the upload_to argument to upload images into the app's static folder without explicitly stating it? I think thats where the issue is. If I use upload_to = 'static/images/articleimages', a new static folder is created in the mysite folder containing manage.py.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you import `STATIC_ROOT` in the `models.py`, and use it to create upload path?

Comment: @RohitJain : I am sorry for being so stupid, but can you elaborate on how to do this please?

Comment: You can do: `from django.conf import STATIC_ROOT`, and then use it there. And it's good to be stupid :)

Comment: @RohitJain Haha, its really not. So just importing it will do the job? I mean after importing and changing upload_to to upload_to = 'images/articleimages', is that it?

Comment: It doesnt work. During migration, it says theres an import error on line 8 in manage.py. Import Error: No module named django.core.management

Comment: No that wouldn't. You need to use: `STATIC_ROOT + '/images/articleimages'`. You can actually pass a callable to `upload_to`, and then in the function, use `os.path.join` utility to build upload path.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Make that: `from django.conf import settings` and use `settings.STATIC_ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

You can import the `STATIC_ROOT` from settings file, and use that to biuld the path. In addition to that, you can use a callable, and build path there instead:

```
import os.path
from django.conf import settings

def generate_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'images/articleimages/')

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    header_image = models.ImageField('article_header_image', upload_to = generate_upload_path)
```

Ok, if you want to upload images to `static` directory of your app, you can use `__path__` attribute of your app:

```
import blog

def generate_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join(blog.__path__, 'static/images/articleimages/')
```

Comment: This still creates a static folder in the mysite folder containing manage.py. I want the image to be uploaded to the static folder inside the blog folder without explicitly stating it in the upload_to argument. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I will test it out tomorrow. The problem is that the server searches for blog/{blog/static/images/articleimages/latest-article-img-1.jpg}. Notice the part in the bracket is the same path in upload_to. So if my upload to was upload_to = 'static/images/articleimages' and it uploaded images to the static folder inside blog, then the problem would be solved. I hope your new method works. Thanks. Oh another question, is this image media or static?

Comment: @NoviceCoder I'm not sure. I myself get confused between them. Let's see if someone else can help here.